# How to test lambda functions in a functional React Component using Jest/Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, jestjs, enzyme

I am attempting to create a pulldown tab, however I haven't gotten anywhere close to adding any functionality because I'm attempting to do this TDD style and I've been incapable of even testing if the function inside of the component triggers on the click event of the button. The jest logs tell me that the object I'm attempting to reference is not a function.

I've attempted to create an instance of the component I'm testing and provide that as an argument to "expect" function using the "toBeCalled" function as a matcher this did not work.

The component itself:

```
import React from "react";
import headerImg from "./headerImg.png";

function PullDown() {
  const displayUPC = () => {};

  return <button onClick={displayUPC} />;
}
export default PullDown;
```

The tests for the Component:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { shallow, mount, configure, instance } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import PullDown from "./PullDown";
import enzyme from "enzyme";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("Pulldown tab", () => {
  let wrapperPulldown;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapperPulldown = shallow(<PullDown />);
  });

  it("should render", () => {
    expect(wrapperPulldown.find("button")).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it("should be clickable", () => {
    wrapperPulldown.find("button").simulate("click");
    expect(wrapperPulldown.displayUPC()).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

I expect the test to fail, and it does, however when I go and add the function to the component and add the onClick with the function attached to the button, the test still fails.Which makes me feel like I haven't done the test correctly.

Comment: `displayUpc` isn't a property of the shallow wrapper (also shallow rendering isn't necessary here). For that matter, it's not a property of the `PullDown` component; it's a local variable in a function. Your component is pointless, so there isn't really a sensible test you *can* write for it. Note that the test failure you expected probably wasn't `is not a function`.

Comment: This is why it's important to "call the shot" (predict the outcome of the test) and compare the actual outcome to what you expected. You probably wanted to see "Expected <something> to have been called, but it was not called.", rather than "wrapperPulldown.displayUPC is not a function", although the fact that displayUpc isn't a mock makes that unlikely anyway.

Comment: You're right! I'm pretty new to all of this, and I'm not sure I understand the point of a shallow render if it isn't to test the functionality of a component? Could you give me some insight on how to properly test the functionality of the button in the component?

Comment: You can't test its functionality, because it doesn't have any. Once it's either updating the DOM or interacting with collaborators you can test for that, but at the moment it doesn't *do* anything.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I thought the point of test driven development was to never write code until you've written a failing test for that codes functionality? So in this instance, how would I write a failing test for this button so I can continue on to writing the actually functionality into it?

Comment: Well what functionality do you want to implement? You haven't actually mentioned that. What will the callback **do**? You don't want to test that the callback gets called, because that's an internal implementation detail (and can't, because it's inaccessible outside the function), so what's the *behaviour*?

Comment: OH GEEZE I'm daft. I'd like the component to render a new div overtop of the main screen that contains an image(kind of like a pulldown in a touchscreen display, but on a onClick as opposed to using swipes). Or perhaps even use css to transition the div down the page. Does that clear things up?

Comment: So when you click on it some additional elements get rendered? Then *test for those* - make sure they don't exist (or are hidden, or have some class that alters their display) prior to the click, and that they're added (or revealed, or have their class list changed) after it.

Comment: So helpful! Thanks man, sorry for being empty headed, that makes way more sense that just testing for some click event.

Comment: That's OK. This is what we mean by **test behaviour, not implementation** - test what the component does (causes some extra elements to get displayed somehow), not how it does it (internal details of click handlers). This frees you up to refactor the how while retaining confidence that the what is unchanged; otherwise, you end up with tests so coupled to your implementation that you have to edit them when you refactor, then you have to recheck that what you're testing is what you actually want all over again.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, the reason is that the function doesn't exist on `ReactWrapper` as this is just an instance around the rendered output. Also, you can't check the function call like you would do in a regular class based component either as it isn't a property on a class e.g. `Pulldown.displayUPC`.

However, there are a couple of different ways you can test similar functionality:

If possible, make the component have no hidden dependencies and pass down function references through props. This isn't always possible if all your components are functional, however.

```
// PullDown.js
function PullDown({displayUPC}) {
  return <button onClick={displayUPC} />;
}
export default PullDown;

// PullDown.spec.js
describe("Pulldown tab", () => {
  let wrapperPulldown;
  let displayUPC;

  beforeEach(() => {
    displayUPC = jest.fn();
  });

  // ... some tests

  it("should be clickable", () => {
    wrapperPulldown = shallow(<PullDown displayUPC={displayUPC} />);
    wrapperPulldown.find("button").simulate("click");
    expect(displayUPC).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Another way to achieve this if you don't have the luxury to pass down the function reference through props is to define the function outside of the component.

```
// PullDown.js
export const displayUPC = () => {};
function PullDown() {
  return <button onClick={displayUPC} />;
}
export default PullDown;

// PullDown.spec.js
import * as pullDownModule from './PullDown.js';
describe("Pulldown tab", () => {
  let wrapperPulldown;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(pullDownModule, 'displayUPC');
    wrapperPulldown = shallow(<PullDown />);
  });

  // ... some tests

  it("should be clickable", () => {
    wrapperPulldown.find("button").simulate("click");
    expect(pullDownModule.displayUPC).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```